# Why won't it pass the test that it should "return an empty array if the property does not exist"

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

The problem:

Given an object and a key, "getEvenElementsAtProperty" returns an array containing all the even elements of the array located at the given key.

Notes:

- If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
- If the array contains no even elements, it should return an empty array.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an empty array.
- If there is no property at the given key, it should return an empty array.

My Code:

```
 var obj = {
 key: [1000, 11, 50, 17]
 }; // sample object


    function getEvenElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
      var arr = []
      if (!obj[key]) arr = [] 
      if (!obj[key] % 2=== 0) arr = []
      for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++){
          if (obj[key][i] % 2 === 0) arr.push(obj[key][i])
      } 
      return arr;
      }
    getEvenElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key') // [1000, 50], yet still doesn't pass
```

Question:

Why do I still get the error saying that it doesn't return an empty array if the property doesn't exist? I thought this is done by line 3:  `if (!obj[key]) arr = []`, if I comment this out the function still returns the same thing.  What is going on with this and how do I return an empty array if the property does not exist.

Comment: Try to use the browser's debugger and trace through the code. Use the watches or console to check the values of `obj[key]`, `!obj[key]`, `!obj[key] %2`, etc... You can break into the debugger by adding the `debugger;` command at the start of the function (and run the code with the browser's developer tools panel open).

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `arr` to an empty array, then conditionally do the same thing twice more. It should be clear that those conditions cannot ever change the behavior of the function, so they can be removed without changing the behavior of the function at all.

If removed, next thing you know `obj[key].length` is evaluated in order to start the loop. But what if `obj[key]` doesn't have a `length`? Error occurs.

What you should be doing is immediately `return []` if any of the necessary conditions for the loop to work does not hold. By the way, those conditions are #3 and #4; a properly written loop will take care of #1 and #2 "for free".

Answer (score 0):

You should employ a fail fast return, so if the key doesnt exist return an empty array. Also using a higher order function like filter makes this process much simpler.

```
var object = {
  moreDescriptiveKeyName: [1000, 11, 50, 17]
};

function getEvenElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (!obj[key]) return []; 
  // var arr = [];
  // for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++){
  //     if (obj[key][i] % 2 === 0) arr.push(obj[key][i])
  // } 
  // return arr;
  return obj[key].filter(function(el, i) {
    return i % 2 === 0
  });
 }
 getEvenElementsAtProperty(object, 'moreDescriptiveKeyName');
```

It is also a good practice to not use 'key' as a key name in an object.